# iOS 7 new phone restore

Tags: icloud, ios

I have an iPhone 4S that I dropped in the toilet. It's fried. So I just bought another iPhone 4S. It turns on as a iOS 6 device, which I set up and I'm activated. I updated it to iOS 7 and now I can't figure out how to restore my old phone's backup. I don't know how to reset without going back to iOS 6. My backup is on iCloud. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have already completed a base setup of your new iPhone (meaning, you have used the **Setup Assistant** to set it up and have reached the home screen). In that case, follow these steps to restore the old phone's iCloud backup into the new iPhone:

- Go to **Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings** and erase it (enter passcode if prompted). The phone will then restart.
- Ensure you have a WiFi connection, and when the **Setup Assistant** shows up

  - Proceed to **Set up your device**
  - Tap **Restore from a Backup**
  - Then sign in to iCloud
  - Proceed to **Choose backup**, then choose from a list of available backups in iCloud.

See:
[Restoring from a previous iCloud backup](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/restoring-from-an-previous-icloud-backup/)
[Restore from iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521)